# Open AVD or emulators without opening Android Studio

Tags: android

90+% of the time, I open Android Studio just to open AVD, then I close Android Studio. Is there a way to open AVD or emulators directly? I'm using Windows 10.

I tried the `avdmanager` command, but there doesn't seem to be a way to open an emulator using it.

I can't find an exe to open the AVD manager directly.

Comment: Try these commands `cd ~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin && ./avdmanager list avd` then your avds are listed, then copy name of device you want to run and then
 run
`cd ~/Android/Sdk/tools | ./emulator -avd NAME_OF_YOUR_DEVICE`. Credits: [Run AVD Emulator without Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718973/run-avd-emulator-without-android-studio)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question today, and I found this nice gist:

```
https://gist.github.com/hidroh/67b2ee7bbdd9038450c00d8a4d69c3fa
```

Notes:

- Added the Android SDK tools/ directory to my PATH.
- Downloaded the gist above onto my desktop to a file called avd.sh.
- Since I have Git for Windows installed, the .sh file opens in Git Bash automatically when I double click it.
- It should find all the emulators you setup in AVD and give you an option to choose which one. Type in the number, and the emulator will
  launch!

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm still curious if it's possible to launch the AVD manager itself without going into Android Studio, so if anyone figures it out let me know.

Comment: Can you clarify what the gist of that gist is? If the link disappears, what should OP do?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did:

```
-I've installed git
-run git bash
-go to this directory Android/sdk/tools/bin (hope you know how to use cd command)
-emulator -list-avds (to get the list of avds)
-emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_7_API_23
```

Nexus_7_API_23 is one of the emulators I made before inside android studio. You select one of yours that you got on your list.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `run-emulator.sh` file with:

```
pushd ${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator
./emulator -list-avds | cat -n
printf "Select AVD: "
read index
avd=$(./emulator -list-avds | sed "${index}q;d")
echo "Selected $avd"
./emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd $avd
popd
```

Give run permissions to file with `chmod +x run-emulator.sh`

Call `./run-emulator.sh`

It will show you a menu with options to quick start any virtual image.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 19.10!

With the environment variables already configured ($ANDROID_HOME), you should be able to list the AVDs, but if you are unable to start the AVD, do the following:

# Check the AVD target name

> emulator -list-avds

# But to start do:

> $ANDROID_HOME/emulator/emulator @avd_name

or

> /home/$USER/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator @avd_name